# Align header beside items in flatlist?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have 2 columns in flatList and I'm trying to align the header component besides the items itself,

Like this
[image: shot1]

But I got the "add image" above then the items below it,

I'm trying to solve it by using `flexWrap` in content container style but since I was using numColumns i got a warning that tells `flexWrap` not supported and use numColumns instead.
so i don't know how can i solve it, so if anybody can help in this case!

here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/flatlist-header)

Code snippet

```
const renderItems = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 0.5, margin: 4 }}>
        <View style={[styles.imgContainer, { borderWidth: 0 }]}>
          <Image
            style={styles.imgStyle}
            source={{
              uri:
                'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcR1K8ypPsfNVQU8lVxl1i2_ajismMS_w6FA4Q&usqp=CAU',
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
  const renderHeader = () => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      // onPress={appeandImgs}
      style={styles.imgContainer}>
      <Image
        style={styles.imgStyle}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://static.thenounproject.com/png/3322766-200.png',
        }}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
  const keyExtractor = (item, index) => String(index);

 <FlatList
          data={[1,2,3]}
          style={styles.flatList}
          numColumns={2}
          renderItem={renderItems}
          ListHeaderComponentStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#ff0',
            width: ScreenWidht / 2 - 20,
          }}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
          columnWrapperStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#f07',
          }}
          contentContainerStyle={{ 
               flexGrow: 1,
               paddingBottom: 12,
               paddingTop: 15,
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Checking your snack, it seems like there are three items in the flexbox FlatList creates. A container containing the header, a container with two items and a container with one item. Because of this structure, I guess your best bet would be to remove the header from the ListHeaderComponent and just put it into the FlatList as second argument.

Comment: Hey @Gh05d, what u mean in "as a second argument"?

Comment: Dont know @Gh05d meant the same thing but you can add a fake item to the array to second index and render the header there conditionally

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan yes that's what i was thinking on it, but i guess will be got some mess :\ in my case, i got images from API firstly, and users can insert the images from his gallery and push it to flatList

Comment: @OliverD true you have to handle it carefully, but styling is also not gonna be easy.